# Python - regex to match url with mongo object id

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regex that matches a url of the following format:

```
/api/v1/users/<mongo_object_id>/submissions
```

Where an example of a mongo_object_id is `556b352f87d4693546d31185`.
I have cooked up the following pattern, but it does not seems to work.

```
/api/v1/users\\/(?=[a-f\\d]{24}$)(\\d+[a-f]|[a-f]+\\d)\\/submissions
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you give example of `mongo_object_id` ?

Comment: 556b352f87d4693546d31185 (also added it in post)

Comment: Please remove the tag from your title. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will do (considering 24 hex chars), using raw keyword before string so no need to escape with double slashes:

```
r'\/api\/v1\/users\/([a-f\d]{24})\/submissions'
```

Python console:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\/api\/v1\/users\/([a-f\d]{24})\/submissions','/api/v1/users/556b352f87d4693546d31185/submissions')
['556b352f87d4693546d31185']
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you do a lookahead _then_ a match?

Comment: I was just fixing original regex, it wasn't clear on this point, but it doesn't really makes sense, thanks for feedback.Actually with more then 24 chars lookahead solution would fail

Answer (score 5):

It looks like an object's ID is a hexadecimal number, which means that it's matched by something as simple as this:

```
[0-9a-f]+
```

If you want to make sure it's always 24 characters:

```
[0-9a-f]{24}
```

Toss that between the slashes:

```
/api/v1/users/([0-9a-f]{24})/submissions
```

And it should work.

Note: You *will* probably have to escape the slashes, depending on how Python's regex syntax works. If I remember right, you can do this:

```
import re
re.findall(r'/api/v1/users/([0-9a-f]{24})/submissions', url)
```

or

```
re.findall(r'/api/v1/users/([0-9a-f]{24})/submissions', url, re.I)
```

if you wanna make the whole thing case-insensitive.