# Unable to sign up for new account in Quora using Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to sign up in Quora programmatically(Java) using Selenium but i am getting error.

- I added `implicitlyWait()` method as well [time
  out set up to 6000]
- Also I added
  `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated()` also in
  a different code[without implicit] wait.

It works till reaching sign up with email page and the throws the following error.Please suggest necessary changes

**Code Snippet**

```
  `  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();        
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.get("http://www.quora.com"); 
     driver.findElement(By.className("signup_email_link")).click();
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='__w2_IDo6rGq_name']")).sendKeys("Test Name");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='__w2_IDo6rGq_email']")).sendKeys("test123@123.com");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*@id='__w2_IDo6rGq_password']")).sendKeys("pass123");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='__w2_IDo6rGq_submit']")).click();`
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='__w2_IDo6rGq_name']"}
Command duration or timeout: 60.31 seconds
```

Comment: Please do not put your tags in your title. You have the tags section for that.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes will you please edit the question to show what is correct way .

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I added 'Selenium/Java' in the question , to summarize the problem while restricting it to the people who have worked on it.I did add the tags as well.
Even you have answered question [Python - regex to match url with mongo object id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559807/python-regex-to-match-url-with-mongo-object-id/30559910#30559910) which has a tag  **Python** in the question without down voting it like you did here.Help me understand the rational and difference between the two cases.

Comment: Oh, hey, didn't see the tag in that one. BRB, downvoting and leaving a comment. See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) for more information. The reason I'm not editing it myself is that edits made by anyone other than the OP are ideally supposed to be fixing as many issues with the post as possible, and I don't know enough about the subject matter to do that. EDIT: Downvoted, comment left. Once the user edits to fix, I'll reverse it and remove the comment.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I got your point ,I was looking for reference in meta,thanks for sharing.Will you please edit my question retaining its meaning.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know enough about the subject matter to edit it properly. It's up to you. It's not hard.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Updated the question as suggested,Please review

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79336/discussion-between-livinggourmand-and-qpaystaxes).

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
both of

```
 driver.findElement(By.className("signup_email_link")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='__w2_IDo6rGq_name']")).sendKeys("Test Name");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='__w2_IDo6rGq_email']")).sendKeys("test123@123.com");
```

xpaths are incorrect. After *.//* you are not specifying any tag or tag independence. Either provide *tagname* or provide `*` as you have done for others. Possibly

```
 driver.findElement(By.className("signup_email_link")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='__w2_IDo6rGq_name']")).sendKeys("Test Name");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='__w2_IDo6rGq_email']")).sendKeys("test123@123.com");
```

Comment: I have made the changes and executed again[takes a lot of time].I will update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Add properties for Thread.sleep.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();        
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get("http://www.quora.com"); 
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@id,'__w2_RcmFYaT_bypass_connect_link')]")).click();
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'__w2_RcmFYaT_name')]")).sendKeys("Test Name");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'__w2_RcmFYaT_email')]")).sendKeys("test123@123.com");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'__w2_RcmFYaT_password')]")).sendKeys("pass123");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'__w2_RcmFYaT_submit')]")).click();`
```

Let me know if it works.. I just modifies xpath and given some wait.

Comment: You suggesting **5s** static delay? That's a real bad practice

Comment: @Hideandseek the xpath is wrong, getting error ` Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@id,'__w2_RcmFYaT_bypass_connect_link')]"}
Command duration or timeout: 17.61 seconds`

Comment: Yes. I suggest 5sec delay.. Check if it's working. Then we will figure out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this will definitely work, id's on quora.com are dynamically generated.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();        
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get("http://www.quora.com"); 
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Sign Up With Email')]")).click();    
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@tabindex='9' and @class='text' and @type='text']")).sendKeys("Test Name");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@tabindex='10' and @class='text' and @type='text']")).sendKeys("test123@123.com");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@tabindex='11' and @class='text' and @type='password']")).sendKeys("pass123");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@tabindex='12' and @class='submit_button']")).click();
```